# Use wp_nav_menu to display ALL pages

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I am currently building a wordpress theme. For the menu, I just want to display all the pages that are created in the order that they are created in (i.e. I don't want users to have to go into the 'menu' section of the site and create their own).

I tried using wp_page_menu and this worked HOWEVER I need to add a walker class to expand the functionality, which you can't do with this function. So I need a way to display all my pages with using wp_nav_menu as my code - is there a way to do this?

Here is my code currently:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'walker' => new Clapton_Nav_Walker ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could move away from `wp_nav_menu()` completely and instead use `wp_list_pages()`.

See the codex for more information, but I believe this may be what you are looking for.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

I do understand that this function outputs the pages. The point I was trying to make though is that you can use this in conjunction with CSS to get it looking like a menu. I made an example page that includes this code:

```
    <?php
/*
* Template Name: Testing
*/
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://nickyoungweb.com/zip/wp-content/themes/THS2012/style.css" />
    <nav id="nav">
         <?php
            wp_list_pages( array(
                'title_li' => ''
            ));
         ?>
       <br style="clear: both; ">
    </nav>
```

I have it linked to a stylesheet that contains this code:

```
    /**** WP LIST PAGES NAV *****/
    nav {  }
    nav li { list-style-type: none; float: left; }
    nav li a { width: 50px; height: 30px; background: #000; color: #fff; padding: 10px; margin: 2px; }
    nav li a:hover { background: #f00; color: #000; }
    nav ul li { display: none; }
```

It is a very basic example of how you could make it work with this function.

Hopefully this helps clear up any confusion I might have caused you and also gives you an idea of how it CAN be done with this function.

Comment: How this will be beneficial? It will just list the pages not a menu.

Comment: Yes it will list all of the pages as the OP wishes to do. There is also an argument for a walker and it can be styled to look like a navigation menu.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestions, but @Chittaranjan is correct, it only outputs the pages, it doesn't act like a menu

Comment: Updated my answer to show a better example of how this could actually work. Link included as a basic example of a menu created using wp_list_pages(). Hope it helps.